# Window.print() jquery not bringing up the printer window in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, printing

I am opening a PDF and displaying it in a new window When the printer icon is clicked the PDF is displayed and the printer invoked. This is working fine in Chrome, but not in IE.

```
$("#printPDF").on("click", function() {
        var url = setPDFRequest();  
        var win = window.open(url, '', "menubar=0,location=0,resizable=1,height=600,width=600");
        win.focus();
        win.print(); 
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The pdf is opening with all the correct data inside the new window, but the system printer window is not opening. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: are you generating the pdf yourself? if so how?

Comment: @borrel - Below is my code to open the pdf. (I am new to stackoverflow so kindly bear with the way i post the code)

ByteArrayOutputStream s = (ByteArrayOutputStream) request.getAttribute("OPEN_PDF");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=XXreport.pdf;");
response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("cache-control", "must-revalidate");
ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
outs.write(s.toByteArray());
outs.flush();
outs.close();

Comment: The above code correctly opens the pdf and also brings the print window in chrome. But in IE, the print window is not showing up.